# Extrema of $f(x) = \frac{xe^x}{1 + 2|3x-1|}$

Tags: calculus

The function is not defined at $x=\frac 1 3$. We can split the function into two cases - $x < \frac 1 3$ and $x > \frac 1 3$. If $x < \frac 1 3$, then $f(x) = \frac{xe^x}{3 - 6x}$ and $f'(x) = \frac{e^x(-2x^2 + x + 1)}{3(1-2x)^2}$ which is equal to zero only at $x = -\frac 1 2$ because of the assumption. Similarly for $x > \frac 1 3$ we have $f'(x) = \frac{e^x(6x^2 - x - 1)}{(6x-1)^2}$ which is zero at $x = \frac 1 2$. So we have two critical points at $x = - \frac 1 2$ and $x = \frac 1 2$ which are both minimums because of how the sign of the derivatives change. Also since $f(-\frac 1 2) < f(\frac 1 2)$ we know that $x = \frac 1 2$ is a local minimum and $x = -\frac 1 2$ is a global minimum. But if we look at the graph of this function:
[image]

the point $x = \frac 1 3$ appears to be a local maximum. But $f$ is not defined at $x = \frac 1 3$ so it's derivative at that point will also be undefined. In my classes we haven't mentioned extrema at undefined points like this so I am confused as to whether or not this can be considered a local maximum or not. If it's worth anything Wolfram Alpha does not count this point as a local maximum. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $f(x)$ is well defined at $x=\frac 13$, it is $f'(x)$ that is not defined there.

Comment: The full conditions for critical points are that $f'=0$ or $f'$ is undefined

Comment: @WW1 Yes, I realized I made a mistake and $f$ is defined at $x = \frac 1 3$. But then that has left me even more confused since both of the derivatives I've found are defined on that point but they aren't zero at it and are different values.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ *is* defined at $x=\frac13$ and this *is* a point of local maximum, since $f$ is increasing on $[-1/2,1/3]$ and decreasing on $[1/3,1/2]$.

Comment: How do i find the $x=1/3$ point analytically. I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: The point $x=1/3$ arises naturally as the point where $|3x-1|$ changes from $-(3x-1)$ to $+(3x-1)$. And $f'$ being defined everywhere else, its sign helps to prove the claim.